# Why is my PDF's Acroform checkbox annotation not rendering in Acrobat Reader?

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I'm working on some code that generates PDF documents. I'm working on generating Acroform checkbox annotations for editable PDF forms, and these render perfectly fine in most of the PDF readers that I'm testing: Chrome, Firefox, Mac Preview, and PDF Element 6. However, I'm really struggling to get these rendering properly in Acrobat Reader.

I've been working on a minimal example PDF that just contains a single checkbox, and no other content.

Here is how the broken PDF looks in Acrobat Reader when I hover / click the checkbox:

[image: broken PDF gif]

The checkbox is invisible by default. When I hover over the checkbox, the border is displayed. But when I click the checkbox, the value isn't persistent, and clicking it again doesn't do anything.

Here is what it's supposed to look like (working PDF from Adobe Acrobat):

[image: working PDF gif]

Here are some links to the PDFs:

- Broken PDF (generated by my code): http://www.filedropper.com/acrobat-minimal-broken
- Working PDF (created in Adobe Acrobat): http://www.filedropper.com/acrobat-checkbox-minimal-working

I have verified both PDFs using [veraPDF](https://verapdf.org/). Both PDFs share a small number of similar validation errors, so this hasn't helped me to figure out the difference.

I even tried to copy the XObject stream directly from the working PDF, and if you look at the /AP => /N => /Yes stream, you should see that they are almost identical:

```
1 g
0 0 36.029 36.029 re
f
0.5 0.5 35.029 35.029 re
s
q
1 1 34.029 34.029 re
W
n
0 g
BT
/ZaDb 33.4305 Tf
2.853 6.3838 Td
32.8405 TL
0 0 Td
(4) Tj
ET
Q
```

(This is a very simple stream that just displays a checkmark using the ZapfDingbats font.)

Unfortunately I can't share any specific code examples. I'm using Ruby and Prawn, but I also have a lot of low-level proprietary code (Prawn doesn't actually have any support for Acroform annotations.) I just need to understand the main differences between these PDFs and figure out why one is broken while the other is rendering properly, and then I will be able to make the changes in my code.

If you are familiar with the PDF specification, then I'd be very grateful if you could please take a look at the PDF files I posted above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You haven't generated an "appearance" stream for the checkbox. Acrobat will add the appearance automatically but if you want Reader to do it, you need to set the Needs Appearances flag in the PDF AcroForm dictionary. Create a new Boolean in the AcroForm called "NeedAppearances" and set it to true. Or you can create the appearance yourself. I haven't verified this so I didn't enter it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @joelgeraci, thanks for your comment! The PDF does include appearance streams for the checkbox, and unfortunately adding the "NeedAppearances" flag doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I saw (later) that but they seem to be constructed wrong. The "Yes" appearance renders as a round dot rather than a check which is what I see in Acrobat. Try adding the NeedsAppearances flag but not creating appearances in the file.

Answer (score 3):

I've finally found the solution! I spent many hours whittling down each PDF until I could find the smallest change that caused this rendering bug in Acrobat Reader. (TIP: Use `pdftk original.pdf output original-uncompressed.pdf uncompress` to uncompress PDF streams, and then you can edit the PDF in a text editor.)

I finally found the culprit under `/Root => /AcroForm => /DA`. The working PDF contained:

```
/DA (/Helv 0 Tf 0 g)
```

The broken PDF had:

```
/DA <feff002f00480065006c0076002000300020005400660020003000200067>
```

This is a hex encoded string with the same decoded value: `/Helv 0 Tf 0 g`.

Most PDF readers will automatically decode this string with no problems (Chrome, Firefox, Mac Preview), but Acrobat Reader doesn't support this for some reason. (Specifically for the `/DA` attribute in an `/AcroForm`. It decodes any other encoded strings perfectly fine.)

I really struggled to spot this issue, because many PDF debugging tools (e.g. [iText RUPS](https://github.com/itext/i7j-rups)) will automatically decode these strings and hide the fact that they were encoded.

I'm working on some PDF generation code in Ruby (using Prawn and the pdf-core gem), so the fix was very simple.

Before:

```
self[:DA] = '/Helv 0 Tf 0 g'
```

After:

```
self[:DA] = PDF::Core::LiteralString.new('/Helv 0 Tf 0 g')
```

Using the `PDF::Core::LiteralString` class prevents Prawn from encoding the string.

After making this change, the checkbox functions properly in Acrobat Reader:

[image: Fixed Acrobat Reader]

Comment: Wow. I use and tool internal to Adobe and it decodes the string too. I suspect Acrobat does as well... just not Reader. Can I share these files with Adobe when I report the bug?

Comment: Yes please feel free to share these files, and thank you for reporting the bug!